# How do I get a GKPlayer's status from Game Center?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, gamekit, game-center

When I get a `GKLocalPlayer` or use `loadPlayersForIdentifiers:identifiers withCompletionHandler:` to get a list or individual `GKPlayer` aliases, the `GKPlayer` object when logged, looks something like this:

```
2010-09-23 10:39:01.759 Cee-lo[76500:207] Players loaded by identity: (
    "<GKPlayer 0x84125a0>(playerID: G:1234567890, alias: typeonetester1, status: Adding test friends., rid:(null))",
    "<GKPlayer 0x8412530>(playerID: G:1234567890, alias: typeonetester2, status: Adding Game Center to app, rid:(null))"
)
```

My question is, how do I get the `status` from this object, and what exactly is the type of this object? There is no "rid" or "status" property in the [GKPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009599) class, so when I do something like:

```
GKPlayer *player = [self.friends objectAtIndex:row];

cell.nameLabel.text = player.alias;
cell.statusLabel.text = player.status;
```

I get a "Request for member 'status' in something not a structure or union" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by an Apple engineer:

> The players' status is not an
>   accessible property.  This was changed
>   in one of the 4.1 betas & is noted in
>   the 4.1 relnotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *desc = player.description;
NSRange range = [desc rangeOfString:@"status:"];
NSString *status = [[desc substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: I don't think you'd get status by trimming whitespace, but this is as good as it gets, it seems.